# how to break 10 digit number into two 5 digit number in c?

Tags: c, split, numbers

Lets say I have a `char[10]="1234567890`. I want it to break it in two 5digits number. I want to ask two thing that do i need to convert it in int before spliting and how will i split it

Comment: use array indexing and memcpy(), then, if you want, strtol().

Comment: Depends on how you need it in your output. If you need it as a `string`, then you need not convert to `int`

Comment: @haris int or string both are good for me

Comment: @user3668172: Then the best way would be what Sourav mentioned, that would keep the output in the `string` format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `char arr[10] = "1234567890"` as per your question, note that it is not a string since it has no room for the NUL terminator (would need size `11`, or left empty `[]` for the compiler to count for you). Assuming you want two strings out of it, you need to copy the two halves to separate arrays, e.g.:

```
char topHalf[6], bottomHalf[6];         // 6 = 5 + NUL
(void) memcpy(topHalf, arr, 5);         // copy 5 chars from beginning of arr
(void) memcpy(bottomHalf, arr + 5, 5);  // arr + 5 to skip the 5 in topHalf
topHalf[5] = '\0';                      // terminate string
bottomHalf[5] = '\0';                   // "
```

Comment: so in this tophalf and bottomhalf will have 5 5 digit numbers

Comment: @user3668172 `topHalf` and `bottomHalf` are each 1 string of length 5, in this case the contents of the string happen to be five digits.

Comment: Why the downvote? It works with the OP's input as given (without fixing the missing terminator), and it is likely to be faster than alternatives _if strings are the desired output_.

Comment: Because giving code for "gimme ze codez" kind of question is bad. SO is about giving fishing rods, not fish.

Comment: @qrdl The question itself may be bad, but that doesn't mean answers are. The time I spend answering bad questions is mine to waste, and my hope is that in the process the asker learns something more than they intended (e.g., lack of terminator in their array of characters).

Comment: @qrdl (and other downvoters) also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions

Comment: @Arkku You didn't understand my previous comment. Your answer was downvoted not because of the question, bad or good, but because of the answer.

Comment: @qrdl I understood that you downvoted the answer because it was an answer to a bad question (i.e., punishing for answering at all), rather than because of anything factually wrong with the answer (i.e., for being a bad answer).

Comment: @qrdl Or if you imply that the answer is bad because it's “giving code”, do observe that it does explain the code _and_ point out a potential other problem in the OP's array. The intent is to be educational rather than “here's your code, copypaste it and go on without learning anything”, and I do believe the answer has enough material to fulfil that intent. Of course it is the reader's responsibility to try and learn from that material, but if they don't, at least I tried and it's still my time to waste as I choose.

Answer (score 1):

ex

```
char num10[]="1234567890";
int n1, n2;
sscanf(num10, "%5d%5d", &n1, &n2);
printf("%d, %d\n", n1, n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

First note that you should write `char arr[11]="1234567890"`, or better still, `char arr[]="1234567890"` since you need to provide space for the null-terminator that comprises the string literal. The compiler will work out the correct size if you don't supply it.

But there is a numerical way of achieving what you want, which will be more efficient than using a string.

1. Either start with a number or convert your string to an `uint64_t`, call that x. You need a 64 bit integer since some 10 digit numbers are too big for a 32 bit integer.
2. Compute x / 100000. That's the more significant part.
3. Compute x % 100000. That's the least significant part.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean something as the following?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char number[10] = "1234567890";
    const size_t N = sizeof( number ) / sizeof( *number );

    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    int *p = &num1;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i == ( N + 1 ) / 2 ) p = &num2;

        *p = *p * 10 + number[i] - '0';
    }

    printf( "num1 = %d, num2 = %d\n", num1, num2 );
}
```

The program output is

```
num1 = 12345, num2 = 67890
```